# Returning the closest time to those stored in a data structure

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

i am currently creating a bus time table app. as of now it gets the current date and time.
I currently have an array of times the bus will be coming next. I want to compare the current time to that of those in the array and return the one closest... representing the next bus. However, there are different timetables for every stop, one for each direction. furthermore they change almost daily.

Is there a nicer data structure anyone can recommend for storing and recalling this data? My code is very messy so would like a better method of comparing,storing and returning data than arrays.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [heap data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) (min-heap).
Each time the top most element will represent the nearest event, so you can remove it operate on it (computing the next event's time) and then insert it again.
it is easy and fast.